# How to print a model object properly in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am new in django, I want to print my data, i am using this function to get data from table, `page_data = Pages.objects.all().filter(id=id)`, i am getting this response `<QuerySet [<Pages: Page 567>]>`, why it shows only title column data ? It should show all the data, can anyone plese help me to show all the data whitin the table with `print` in cmd ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see each property data by accessing using the property name like

```
page_data.id 
page_data.title
```

By default the the query set will display only the primary key of the record as a tag for the query set which is why you see the id value 567 in `[<Pages: Page 567>]`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to print the object.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should be looking at overriding `__str__()` method to return whatever data you want from an object in Django Model.

Here you go.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str

You can also get any column value of the object using the below format.

```
object_name.column1_name

object_name.column2_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a dictionary representation of a Django model object, you can access the `__dict__` attribute:

```py
model_object = Pages.objects.all().filter(id=id).first()
print(model_object.__dict__)
```

As a bonus, to do a colorized pretty print (e.g. in the `./manage.py shell` REPL environment):

```
>>> from rich import pretty, print
>>> pretty.install()
>>> model_object.__dict__
```